# How to disable LG LT1216CER Thermistor

Tags: repair, walls, air-conditioning, cooling

MY air conditioner's compressor keeps turning off before the desired temperature of the room is reached. I was told I could disable that feature by getting rid of the thermistor. Is this a safe alternative or is the unit broken?

Comment: Have you turned the set point temp to the lowest value? If you would remove the thermistor, I think it is possible the unit would not work at all. Does the thermistor unplug or would you have to cut wires to disconnect it?

Comment: The problem with totally disabling it is it may start freezing up, you can shift the temp range, there are even kits to do this to make walk in coolers but totally disabling may damage the unit.